# Smarty error: modifier 'unescape' is not implemented

Tags: php, html, smarty

I want smarty to show html variable content like it is a part of the html file, so I use "unescape" modifier like it is show [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl):

```
<div id="add">{if $add}{$add|unescape:"html"}{/if}</div>
```

But i get:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in xxx.html line 20]: [plugin] modifier 'unescape' is not implemented (core.load_plugins.php, line 118) in
XXX/inc/lib/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095
```

My plugin directory in the correct place:

```
Smarty$ ls
Config_File.class.php  Smarty.class.php  Smarty_Compiler.class.php  debug.tpl  error_log  internals  plugins
```

What can be wrong and how I can do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dealing with it via php:

```
<div id="add">
    {if $add}
        {php}
            echo html_entity_decode($add);
        {/php}
    {/if}
</div>
```

You can play arround with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function to fit your needs, or you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` as Smarty [unascape](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl) function suggests.